# Regular expression issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to get all the power calculations out of a string using reg exp's i tried the following code:

```
var regex = new RegExp('[0-9]+[^]{1}[0-9]+');
regex.exec('1^2');
```

this works and returns 1^2 but when i try to use the following string:

```
regex.exec('1+1^2');
```

it returns `1+1`

Comment: `^` is not operator. Try `[0-9]+[\^]{1}[0-9]+`

Comment: You need to escape the caret - i.e. `[/^]`

Comment: Do you expect "1+1^2" to match at all?  It won't if you fix the `^` issue.

Comment: @Imray Escaping should be done on the opposite side, using backslash `[\]`.

Answer (score 6):

This is because `[^xyz]` means "not x, y, or z." `^` is the "not" operator in character classes (`[...]`). To fix this, simply escape it (one backslash to escape the `^`, and another to escape the first backslash since it's in a string and it's a special character):

```
var regex = new RegExp('[0-9]+[\\^]{1}[0-9]+');
```

Also, you don't need to use character classes and the `{1}` if you only have one character; just do this:

```
var regex = new RegExp('[0-9]+\\^[0-9]+');
```

Finally, one more improvement - you can use literal regular expression syntax (`/.../`) so you don't need two backslashes:

```
var regex = /[0-9]+\^[0-9]+/;
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fXE5N/1/)

Comment: `[0-9]+\^[0-9]+` won't work - it needs 2 escape slashes: `[0-9]+\\^[0-9]+`

Comment: @Imray good point, but it will work in literal regex notation (`/.../`). Updated answer.

Comment: @Doorknob My problem is that i need it to work with multiple power calculation and this regex only seems to pick the first one it encounters even when using .match()

Comment: Note that `^` negates the character class only when it is at the start of the character class. It loses its meaning elsewhere

Comment: Ya but its about the character ^ not the regex sign

Answer (score 4):

`[^]` in regex terms is a character class (`[]`) that's been inverted (`^`). e.g. `[^abc]` is "any character that is **NOT** a, b, or c". You need to escape the carat: `[\^]`.

As well, `{1}` is redundant. Any character class or individual character in a regex has an implied `{1}` on it, so `/a{1}b{1}c{1}/` is just a very verbose way of saying `/abc/`.

As well, a single-char character class is also redundant. `/[a]/` is exactly the same as `/a/`.